# Asset Catalog Compile Error - TDDIstiller instance can only be distilled only one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image

So, I have an app that I am building in Xcode, and things have been going pretty well for a while.  However, suddenly I am getting the error:

```
Images.xcassets: error: ERROR: Each TDDistiller instance can be distilled only one time!
```

***So, two problems:***

**1)** I have no idea what that means, and neither does Google, Bing, or Yahoo, apparently.

**2)** I have no idea how to fix it.  I haven't changed my asset catalog in months, so I don't know what could have introduced this fault.

Here is the error log for the build:

```
2015-01-07 19:41:57.348 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1226:17469] 
BOMStorage BOMStorageNewWithOptionsAndSys(const char *, 
CFDictionaryRef, BomSys *) can't open: 
'/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-
eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/Assets.car' Permission denied  2015-
01-07 19:41:57.349 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1226:17469] Error: 
unable to create storage file 
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-
eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/Assets.car error 'No such file or 
directory' /* com.apple.actool.errors */ 
/Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets: 
error: ERROR: Each TDDistiller instance can be distilled only one 
time! /* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
```

`/Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[iphone][57x57][1x]: notice: 57x57 app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0 /Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[iphone][57x57][2x]: notice: 57x57@2x app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0 /Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][50x50][1x]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0 /Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][50x50][2x]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0 /Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][72x72][1x]: notice: 72x72 app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0 /Users/user/Documents/Videographer/Videographer/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[ipad][72x72][2x]: notice: 72x72@2x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0 /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */` `/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon29x29.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon57x57.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon57x57@2x.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon50x50~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon50x50@2x~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon72x72~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon72x72@2x~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/Assets.car /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Intermediates/Videographer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Videographer.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist`

***Any ideas?  I am in Xcode 6.1.1 working on a project targeting iOS 8.1.***

Comment: Would be great if anyone can explain what this error means!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Clearing the DerivedData folder for the project eliminated the error for me.

Comment: sorry i am not getting help after clearing derived data . My project was created Xcode 8.3 and then i have updated my macOS to high sierra(10.13.2) and Xcode to 9.2 and after that i am getting error "Each TDDistiller instance can be distilled only one time!" this is Assets.xcassets related problem . Please help

Answer (score 8):

Quitting Xcode, quitting Simulator, re-opening Xcode and re-running the build afresh has worked for me. No idea though what this error is all about!

Answer (score 6):

In my case something, probably to do with CocoaPod, was causing my `Build` directory to be created with a lowercase ***`build`***. The Distiller was then looking for the ***Asset.car*** file in the uppercase ***`Build`*** directory as you can see from this part of the log

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Videographer-
eubeafyfmzewucdlcmfhmdsusjng/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/Videographer.app/Assets.car error 'No such file or 
directory'
```

And not finding it. By manually renaming the `build` directory to `Build` I was able to resolve this error. However, I assume this is only a temporary fix as whatever set the directory to `build` probably still exists.

Comment: There is no **build** directory in `DerivedData` folder

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 9.4 now and still this problem.
After several attempts, deleting all the content of the DerivedData folder worked for me following this sequence:

1. /Product/Clean
   [image: menu image product clean]
2. Xcode/Preferences..Locations. Open Derived Data in finder (with the arrow)
   [image: click the arrow after the derivedData folder prompt]

3.**Close Xcode**.

4.Delete all content of the derivedData folder (it's a cache).

5.Empty trash.

6.Open Xcode and run project.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I tried above all solutions but in vain. So the following worked for me.

1.In XCode Go to File -> Project settings

2.Click the Advanced button

3.Select "Custom" and select "Relative to Workspace" in the pull down

4.Set "Build/Products" in Products field if not set in my case there was other value. Then click on Done.

[image]

Comment: just migrated to a new macbook withMojave and Xcode 10. the same problem occurred. Thanks GSK, this solution worked for me!

Comment: This technique doesn't fix OP's issue.  I am still getting the error "**Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code**"

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Xcode9 and reinstalling it

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to solve this is to remove all the DerivedData using this command:

```
    rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

The above command really worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything here, including uninstalling XCode to varying levels of completeness.  The only thing that fixed this for me was creating a new project from scratch, and re-adding all my files and settings.

(But you see, it's actually better that way, it Just Works!  Why would you ever want to run a project in XCode anyway?  Besides, if you have an old project, this is just Apple's way of making sure you're staying up to date.  Imagine what kind of bigger problems you'd have if they didn't do this! ;)

Answer (score 1):

No need to clear DerivedData folder. **Product > Clean Build Folder** seems to be enough in this case.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky how can you know that? It worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [zode64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46989365/2684720)'s answer. I do not use cocoaPod, in my case I have problem with my product name.

Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943021/2684720). Editing project.pbxproj fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just `Product-Clean` can help this out. 
If not, it's time to delete your folder at `/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: Build error: 
**Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code**

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had Xcode 12.0 beta version installed. Switching to 12.2 (not beta) solved the problem.

Apple Dev issue: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658421