# What is the way to reset Archive -iOS files when they are not found

Tags: ios, swiftui, build, archive

hey, I am an Android developer, but I also would like to learn iOS to make my apps into iOS. I turned in my app for Apple consideration, but it was rejected. I fixed the issues they mention, but when I try to create a new build, I get No such file or directory for files that I know exist, but I do not find the way to fix it on the web.

[image]

I already saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921748/xcode-error-no-such-file-or-directory-when-building), and I have not been able to find something close to the solution.

Please, guide me on what you think it is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Your folders is not in project path. Please be sure selected 'copy items if needed' when you add a item.

[image]

Comment: yeah, I made sure this step was done. That is done. and I still get the error. I cannot explain how the first build did not brake, but the others have.

Comment: I saw 'Downloads/Lore/...' this line in your post. Be sure your items path is in project path. Clear references and try to copy again.

Comment: I tried that and no results. I even removed the files from the fonts folder, the Copy Bundles Resources at Build Phases and I still get the same error. Is there a place I should check to see how that is looking for the files in that location?

Comment: When you click item in XCode you can see a path in right side of Xcode. Identity and Type section. https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/35bc80c902/d373ed5c-a36b-46fe-9bd8-bf49700072be.png You can see full path.

Comment: I am able to see the path there and it says "/Users/myname/Downloads/Noto_Serif/Noto.ttf", is that not the same as what is shown in the image except with no Users/myname/?

Comment: It needs to look like such as: /Users/ComputerName/Documents/ProjectName/Resources/Font/Noto_Serif/Noto.ttf. Your path is wrong. You can use font but your fonts is not in project path because you are receiving error. Remove and add again and do not forget 'Copy items if needed.'

Comment: It does not look like that, but all the other steps are in place for it to work. Do I have to copy the files from the Downloads folder and paste them somewhere else? I just don't think so. It would just be in another folder.